# Property is undefined inside a component - React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

When I run the app I get the error: "Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined" on my `items` property. After debugging I found out that the property items was undefined only inside the component.
I have already defined `items` in my mapStateToProps function and in my reducer.

This is the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import ListItemCont from '../containers/list-item.js';

class ListComp extends React.Component {
    constructor (props){
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        let itemsComponents = [];
        this.props.items.forEach((item) => {
            itemsComponents.push(
                <ListItemCont description={item.description}
                              header={item.header}>
                </ListItemCont>)
        });

        return(
            <ul>
                {itemsComponents}
                <button onClick={this.props.onAddClick()}></button>
                <button onClick={this.props.onRemoveClick()}></button>
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

export default ListComp;
```

This is my container:

```
import {addItem, removeItem} from '../actions/list.js';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import ListComp from '../components/list.jsx';

const mapStateToProps = (stateProps, ownProps) => {
    return {
        items: stateProps.items
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onAddClick: () => {
            dispatch(addItem());
        },
        onRemoveClick: (item) => {
            dispatch(removeItem(item));
        }
    }
};

const ListCont = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ListComp);
export default ListCont;
```

And this is my reducer:

```
import {LIST_ACTIONS} from '../utilities/consts.js';
import {addItem, removeItem} from '../actions/list.js';

const initialState = {
    items: []
};

export const listReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case LIST_ACTIONS.ADD_ITEM: {
            return Object.assign({}, state, {items: [...items, action.item]});
        }
        case LIST_ACTIONS.REMOVE_ITEM: {

            let itemIndex = state.item.indexOf(action.item);
            return Object.assign({}, state, {items: [
                    ...state.items.slice(0, itemIndex),
                    ...state.items.slice(itemIndex + 1)
                ]});
        }
        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
};
```

What am I missing here? I have no idea why items is undefined.

Comment: i think it should be `stateProps.listReducer.items` you need to specify the reducer also.

Comment: @MayankShukla It still does not work, It says that I'm trying to update the state inside the render method and causes re-rendering in an infinite loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Changes:**

1- It should be `stateProps.listReducer.items`, you need to specify the reducer name also.

2- onClick expect a function, what you are doing here is, you are directly calling those functions instead of passing them as event handler, So write it like this:

```
<button onClick={this.props.onAddClick}></button>         //here remove ()
<button onClick={this.props.onRemoveClick}></button>      //here remove ()
```

When you write:

```
onClick={this.props.onAddClick()}
```

`onAddClick` function will get called automatically whenever component render (without clicking on button).

**Reason for infinite loop:**

```
   render   ---->   onAddClick()   ----->   reducer state update--
     ^                                                           |
     |                                                           |
     |                                                           |
      -----------------------------------------------------------
```

Check the DOC: **[Handling Events in JSX.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html)**

Answer (score 1):

as far as I can see the problem is here:

```
        <ul>
            {itemsComponents}
            <button onClick={this.props.onAddClick()}></button>
            <button onClick={this.props.onRemoveClick()}></button>
        </ul>
```

this should be:

```
       <ul>
            {itemsComponents}
            <button onClick={this.props.onAddClick.bind(this)}></button>
            <button onClick={this.props.onRemoveClick.bind(this)}></button>
        </ul>
```

In your case the functions are getting executed as soon as it renders. Thus updating the state in render and causes infinite loop.

another syntax is:

```
<button onClick={() => this.props.onAddClick() } ></button>
```